# Partial import of antd package not working

Tags: webpack, babeljs, antd

I am importing antd package using the `babel-plugin-import` plugin. However, I am getting the warning that the whole bundle is imported.

> You are using a whole package of antd, please use
>   https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import to reduce app bundle
>   size.

My webpack config for jsx is as follows:

```
{
    test: /\.jsx$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: [nodeModulesDir],
    options: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        plugins: [
            'transform-decorators-legacy',
            'add-module-exports',
            ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": true }],
            ["react-transform", {
                transforms: [
                    {
                        transform: 'react-transform-hmr',
                        imports: ['react'],
                        locals: ['module']
                    }
                ]
            }]
        ],
        presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
    }
},
```

For some reason, the entire antd bundle is being imported.

Comment: How did you import antd component?

Comment: The usual way: `import { Button } from 'antd'`

Comment: I found a note `babel-plugin-import will be not working if you add the library in webpack config vendor.` in the [babel-plugin-import doc](https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import#note).

Comment: I have only the app bundle / chunk. No vendor chunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I created a package `searchtabular-antd`. The package used babel transpiler to output javascript. The below line in the package caused the problem:

```
import { DatePicker, Checkbox, Input, InputNumber } from 'antd';
```

The components should be manually imported from lib as follows:

```
import DatePicker from 'antd/lib/date-picker';
```

This fixed the antd size in the main app which used searchtabular-antd.